# Ruby installer on Windows 7 64-bit machine

Tags: ruby, windows-7, installation, 64-bit

Can anyone please help me where to find Ruby 64-bit installer to be installed on Windows 7 or can I install 32-bit ruby 1.8.6 or 1.9 installers(only one) on a 64-bit machine without any problem?. Any recommendations or links for documentation would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Windows 7 for quite a while now. Standard 32-bit Ruby 1.8.6 one-click installer works. I can both run Rails applications and "even" debug the code in NetBeans.
[Downloaded from here](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)

Comment: Please note that if you use Ruby Java Bridge, Java MUST be of the same word length as Ruby. So, if you do not have 64-bit Ruby, you have no choice - JAVA_HOME must point to 32-bit JDK.

Answer (score 11):

32bits Ruby can be installed in 64bits Windows versions thanks to WOW64 (Windows on Windows functionality)

There is no *Installer* for 64bits Ruby, and you will find a lot of complications in that front.

I recommend you use the upcoming RubyInstallers from official RubyInstaller website:

http://rubyinstaller.org/

(Will be redirected to RubyForge, locate Preview 2 installers there). Both 1.8.6 and 1.9.1 are available.

Also, if you want more step to step instructions, please take a look to some tutorials we have collected here:

http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/tutorials

Hope that helps.

Comment: FYI: Luis is the maintainer, lead developer and original author of RubyInstaller. So, if he says it works, then it works. :-)

Comment: It seems people have been compiling Ruby for 64-bits on unixes for a while now. You wrote "you will find a lot of complications in that front". Are you guys working on a 64-bit Ruby installer for Windows?

Comment: Ruby on unixes is different than Ruby on Windows. Ruby has a lot of dependencies that needs to be compiled in 64bits too to actually use it. See my post here:

http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rubyinstaller-devel/2008-January/000230.html

Answer (score 3):

As of March 2013, the RubyInstaller team produce a 64 bit Windows build of Ruby 2.0 . My thanks to them.

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

But all 32 bit software works normally on Windows 7 anyway - that's worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby team is still working on a 64-bit compiled version of Ruby for Windows. The 32-bit version works provided you do not need win32ole to work consistently. You will get a "Class Not Registered" error in some cases trying to instantiate a 64-bit OLE interface.

Latest I have seen on the ruby installers list is: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/b628af0efaaae5bd

This impacts some gems like virtualbox: http://github.com/mitchellh/virtualbox/issues#issue/37